# How does Python determine which coordinates is greater?

Tags: python-3.x, list, coordinates

Say, I have two lists each containing just a pair of coordinates:

list1 = [2,1]

list2 = [1,2]

list3 = [2,3]

Why does `list1 > list2` evaluate to  `True`

but `list2 > list3` evaluate to `false`?

Comment: It's comparing element by element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compares element by element until it finds two different values at which point it returns either `True` or `False` depending on which list contains the larger value. It is equivalent to the following:

```
def compare(a, b):
    # Equivalent to a > b
    for i, j in zip(a, b):
        if i > j:
            return True
        elif i < j:
            return False
    return False
```